# How to create area chart with react using highcharts

Tags: reactjs, react-native, charts, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm new with react and I would like to create an area chart with react so it will look like this:

[image]

I need:

- to display 2 different data (in the attached example, like 'USE' and 'USSR/Russia'
- the y axis should be percentage (25%, 50%, 75%, 100%)
- the x axis should be dates ( 24 May, 25 May , 26 May ...)

I couldn't find any example on how to achieve this kind of chart.

any ideas? or links to some example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example of the area chart in Highcharts React Wrapper:

**Simplified code:**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
// Import Highcharts
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      options: {
        series: [
          {
            type: 'area',
            data: [1, 2, 3]
          }
        ],
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={this.state.options}
      />
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Demo:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-hvtvky

**Docs References:**
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-react-wrapper/

Comment: Use `labels.format` to change the unit; To change the range of xAxis, use axis.min and max options. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rf0og1sh/